# Import non-english Wikipedia XML dump in MySQL?

Tags: sql, xml, import, wikipedia

I'm looking for a script that can convert the XML wikipedia DUMP in MySQL compliant SQL. I've found a ready SQL dump for the english version but no easy way to import the other languages.

Thanks,

Piero

Answer (score 3):

Per [wikipedia's own page on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database) (well worth studying), help for importing wikipedia xml dumps to mysql is found on [this mediawiki page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps) .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but as far as I've understood it will import the Mediawiki format while I'm intrested in the Html content so I'll need something that works with the results...

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has an API

- http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
- http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
- http://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
- (...)

You can use this API to iterate over the articles and to download each page.

Comment: This was my original idea infact I was looking for a "ready" script that could do this..